# system() mangles the command in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to execute a command through system() in PHP. The command is /usr/bin/unzip, but the function returns with the error code 127. There is nothing else outputted. If I run the very same command directly in a shell it works.

The apache error log says 'sh: /unzip: not found'. I have also tried to put the command into a shell script that is in the same directory as the PHP script and call the shell script through system(). The same happens: if the shell script was called 'doit.sh' the error message in the apache log would be 'sh: /doit.sh: not found'.

exec() has the same behaviour.

The PHP version is 5.2.11-2 with suhosin extensions.

Any ideas what PHP could be doing to my command?

Comment: system('/usr/bin/unzip somestuff', $retval); var_dump($retval); 
what else do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off safe mode in php.ini.

If safe mode is on and the `safe_mode_exec_dir` property is empty you'll get exactly the same behaviour as described.

Comment: I thought it was off, which it was globally, but not locally.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than shelling out to unzip things, you could just use [PHP's zip functions](http://php.net/zip).

Answer (score 3):

It looks as if you are sending the command 'unzip' when you should be using '/usr/bin/unzip'

If not, then, have you checked if your webserver runs in a chroot environment?

C.

Comment: When I look under /proc/<pid>/root it shows the real /, so I guess it's not chrooted

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try just with command name ?

```
system('unzip somestuff', $retval);
```